# Hide table when search results 0

Tags: javascript, html, search, hide

I have a table and a search textbox. I am filtering the table when I type something in the searchbox using this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Write on keyup event of keyword input element
    $("#buscador").keyup(function(){

        var $rows1 = $('#tablaproyectos1 tbody>tr');
        $('#buscador').keyup(function() {
            var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

            $rows1.show().filter(function() {
                var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                return !~text.indexOf(val);
            }).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

My question is:  How can I hide the table when there are no results from the search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Write on keyup event of keyword input element
    $("#buscador").keyup(function(){

        var $rows1 = $('#tablaproyectos1 tbody>tr');
        $('#buscador').keyup(function() {
            $('#tablaproyectos1').show();
            var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

            $rows1.show().filter(function() {
                var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                return !~text.indexOf(val);
            }).hide().addClass('hide');
            if ($('#tablaproyectos1 tbody>tr:visible').length == 0) {
              $('#tablaproyectos1').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="buscador" />
<table id="tablaproyectos1" style="border: 2px solid blue;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Esto es una prueba de celda</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Texto de relleno</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Otra celda de prueba</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Suficiente para comprobar el buscador</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

It works counting the visible rows. If total length of this is 0, then hide parent table. Table is always showed at the beginning.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am having a little trouble. In your code snippet it works perfect, but when i put the code in my page, it hides the table, but if i delete the text on the textfield, the table does´t show up again. What can i do?

Comment: fixed it. I just removed     .addClass('hide')

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I try first hiding table by class, and I forget to remove this code.